# Suggestion on a subscription based database schema

Tags: mysql, database, schema, subscriptions

I'm creating a subscription based service with payment gateway, discounts and other feature. I am stuck at a point on how to manage the subscriptions, transactions and invoice.

**My tables are:** (I've listed only the relevant tables below )

- users
- packages (package_id being the P.K )
- subscriptions
- transactions
- transaction_details

[image: DB Schema]

Using the above structure I won't be able to create/ store the invoice, won't be able to apply any discount for the subscription and difficult to manage any refund/ cancellation.

Any suggestions to improve the structure would be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you provide more details on each entity and how the entities relate to each other?